# Software RAID on Debian 6 VM

Tags: debian, raid, virtual-machines

I was thinking of setting up a software RAID on my VMs running Debian OS 6.

I found a guide:
"http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Software-RAID-HOWTO-5.html"
, but it seems like my system lacks a "/proc/mdstat" file. So I am making an assumption that the current setup just does not have a RAID support.

Has any1 tried setting up a software RAID on Virtual servers with virtual disks ?
Any luck ?

Comment: Have you read the very first line of text on the link you gave? "This HOWTO is deprecated; the Linux RAID HOWTO is maintained as a wiki by the linux-raid community at http://raid.wiki.kernel.org/"

Comment: Also: If you want to use a RAID inside a VM, you have to make sure that your underlying physical hardware matches this goal. Example: If you have only one physical disk to store your disk images, using a RAID will bring you no benefit at all.

Answer (score 0):

What the goal of using raid inside VM? Some outside dublication?

Not of all virtualization technology provides full access to kernel modules (like openvz), so i think md may not works here normally.

first of all, you can try installing mdadm.
apt-get install mdadm

Answer (score 0):

To have `/proc/mdstat` you have to have MD drivers loaded. Try one of the following:

```
modprobe raid0
modprobe raid1
modprobe raid10
modprobe raid456
```

depending on what type of RAID you want to do.

That being said, the only reason you may want to run RAID in the VM is to *test* the configuration for physical machines. Not only using RAID in the host is faster, but also safer for data.